# Change color of button with jQuery when radio input is selected

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to make the button a different color if a specific radio input is chosen.

This is the html code 
 
         Brown
         Blonde
         Red

```
    <h3>Skincolor</h3>
    <div class="skin">
        <span style="cursor:pointer"><div class="skincolor" id="fair"><input type="radio" name="skin" value="fair">Fair</div></span>
        <span style="cursor:pointer"><div class="skincolor" id="dark"><input type="radio" name="skin" value="dark">Dark</div></span>
        <span style="cursor:pointer"><div class="skincolor" id="inbetween"><input type="radio" name="skin" value="middle">Middle</div>
```

Find her

I'm using jQuery so I should be able to change the css in the JS code but for some reason I won't get it to work.

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
$("#brown").click(function() {
    $("#blonde").toggle();
    $("#red").toggle();



});
$("#blonde").click(function() {
    $("#brown").toggle();
    $("#red").toggle();

});
$("#red").click(function() {
    $("#blonde").toggle();
    $("#brown").toggle();

});
$("#fair").click(function() {
    $("#dark").toggle();
    $("#inbetween").toggle();

});
$("#dark").click(function() {
    $("#fair").toggle();
    $("#inbetween").toggle();

});
$("#inbetween").click(function() {
    $("#dark").toggle();
    $("#fair").toggle();

});



});


}

if($('input:radio[name="hair"]:checked')){
$("#brown").css('background-color', "red")
}
```

Comment: You've got a syntax error in your snippet. The `}

if($('input:radio[name="hair"]:checked')){
$("#brown").css('background-color', "red")
}` should be `if($('input:radio[name="hair"]:checked')){
$("#brown").css('background-color', "red")
}`.

Comment: changed that but it still isn't working.

Comment: Try putting `if($('input:radio[name="hair"]:checked'))` into the click handler for the radio button.  There is nothing in the code above that causes that line to be executed when the radio button becomes checked.

Comment: Cheers :) That worked!